# Build Breaker Setup Sonar

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube

Does anyone know any tutorials of how to setup the build breaker plugin on Sonar so that it fails the build after it reaches a certain threshold on critical issues. I tried using the official docs: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Build+Breaker+Plugin but they don't provide much documentation. 
As of now, the build breaker plugin is not running as expected. It gives an alert if there is a new critical issue, but it doesn't break the build.

Answer (score 1):

You must first define some alerts on the Quality Profile you're using. For instance : error if critical issues > 0. Then you must install the Build Breaker plugin and each new upcoming SonarQube analysis will fail if there are some critical issues. If you don't manage to make it work could you attach to your question, the SonarQube analysis log file ?